# Somehow broke ZSH on new Mac 2020. I launch terminal but do not see the expected ~$

Tags: zsh

Somehow broke ZSH on my new Macbook 2020. I launch the terminal but do not see the expected ~$ I can run commands but would like the prompt back.

Have spent the last couple of hours searching to no avail.

Ideas?

Comment: Restore your `.zshrc` file to default?

Comment: ... or rename that file (which is in your home folder) if it's easier.

Comment: Can you post the content of your current .zshrc ?    (cat ~/.zshrc )

Answer (score 1):

Your system default prompt will be declared in `/etc/zshrc`. AFAIK, Apple's default is this:

```
# Default prompt
PS1="%n@%m %1~ %# "
```

If you wish to change that, declare a different value for `PS1` in your `~/.zshrc` file. There are numerous resources for customizing the `zsh` prompt - [here's one](https://www.makeuseof.com/customize-zsh-prompt-macos-terminal/), for example.

If you change anything in `~/.zshrc`, reload it as follows:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```